# Limited cpupower policy scaling

Tags: linux, cpu-frequency

How do I change the cpufreq policy range?

```
$ cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: powernow-k8
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0 1
  maximum transition latency: 109 us
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.00 GHz
  available frequency steps:  2.00 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 800 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
```

You can see that hardware limit is at 2GHz, but policy limit is at 800. Trying

```
$ sudo cpupower frequency-set --max 2000000 
Setting cpu: 0
Setting cpu: 1
```

but without effect:

```
$ cpupower frequency-info --policy
analyzing CPU 0:
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 800 MHz.
                  The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
```

I've tried echoing the values directly:

```
echo 2000000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

no dice.

The issue happens on xubuntu 17.04 x86_64 and on latest Majnaro i686, so I don't believe it's distro specific.

Comment: I did some searching and it appears to be this bug as documented at kernel.org: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=189291